# WordPress Title Position

Tags: wordpress

My titles on other pages (not home) say; example:
About Us | MyWebsiteTitle
(page title)(separator)(website title)

How do I change this to show:
MyWebsiteTitle | About us
(website title)(separator)(page title)

My current code for header.php is:

```
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
```

I have no idea how im going to do this, so I can't show what i've already tried, and I also have no idea how to word this question to search for it.

Comment: Are you sure that's your current code? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title indicates the function doesn't output the website's name, just the page's.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm sure, I used underscores.me to generate the theme. Also thats what I found weird.

Comment: Ah, http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_title indicates a theme/plugin can override it. Take a look in the theme's `functions.php` file and see if they're hooking into the `wp_title` filter.

Comment: @ceejayoz No results found. Any other ideas on why this is happening? I also ran a search on `title`.

Comment: Run the search on the entire `wp-content/plugins` directory to see if the filter is through a plugin. You could also try disabling all of your plugins.

Comment: @ssergei It's ok now, I found a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Mind sharing what your workaround is?

Comment: @ssergei I did, check answers.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress plugin named `Yoast WordPress SEO` solves this problem with an inbuilt system to override all titles.